# Attaching space in topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

I have some problem understanding the attaching space when learning topology. We know that

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two spaces, $A$ a subset of $Y$ , and $f: A\to Y$  a continuous map. The quotient space $$ X \bigcup\limits_{f}Y:= (X\bigsqcup Y)/[a \sim f(a),\,\,\forall a\in A]$$ 
is called the result of attaching or gluing the space Y to the space X via f. The map $f$ is the attaching map.

$X\bigsqcup Y$ space defined by $$X\bigsqcup Y = \{(x; X)\,\,|\,\,x\in X\} \bigcup \{(y; Y)\,\,|\,\,y\in Y\}.$$

I don't understand this $\sim$ relation. If $(x_1; x_2), (y_1; y_2)\in X\bigsqcup Y$ then

$$ (x_1; x_2) \sim (y_1; y_2)\leftrightarrow ??$$

Can you explain for me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I’m assuming that $A$ is in fact a subset of $X$, not $Y$.

Let’s simplify matters a little by assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, so that we don’t have to form $X\sqcup Y$; I’ll return to the general case later. We have disjoint spaces $X$ and $Y$, a subset $A$ of $X$, and a continuous $f:A\to Y$. The idea is that we’re going to attach $Y$ to $X$ by ‘gluing’ $A$ to $f[A]$ in a manner determined by the function $f$. Specifically, we’ll glue each $x\in A$ to the corresponding point $f(x)\in f[A]$. Note that since $f$ need not be injective, some points of $f[A]$ may be glued to several different points in $A$; these points of $A$ then end up glued to one another as well.

This gluing is formally accomplished by defining an equivalence relation in such a way that each equivalence class consists of a set of points that are to be glued together. If $x\in X\setminus A$, we don’t want to glue $x$ to any other point, so we want $[x]$, the equivalence class of $x$, to be just $\{x\}$. The same goes for points of $Y\setminus f[A]$. If $x\in A$, however, we want to glue $x$ to $f(x)$ and to all other points $x'\in A$ such that $f(x')=f(x)$, so we want

$$[x]=\{f(x)\}\cup\{x'\in A:f(x')=f(x)\}\;.$$

Similarly, for $y\in f[A]$ we want

$$[y]=\{y\}\cup f^{-1}[\{y\}]\;.$$

We do this by defining $\sim$ as follows: for $u,v\in X\cup Y$, $u\sim v$ if and only if one of the following is true:

- $u=v$;
- $u\in A$ and $v=f(u)$;
- $v\in A$ and $u=f(v)$;
- $u,v\in A$ and $f(u)=f(v)$.

This all works fine if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, but of course they may not be, so in general we have to start by forming their disjoint union

$$\begin{align*}
X\sqcup Y&=(X\times\{X\})\cup(Y\times\{Y\})\\
&=\{\langle x,X\rangle:x\in X\}\cup\{\langle y,Y\rangle:y\in Y\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

The point here is that since $X\ne Y$, $\langle x,X\rangle\ne\langle y,Y\rangle$ no matter what $x$ and $y$ are, so the sets $X\times\{X\}$ and $Y\times\{Y\}$ really are disjoint, but on the other hand there are obvious bijections

$$X\to X\times\{X\}:x\mapsto\langle x,X\rangle$$

and

$$Y\to Y\times\{Y\}:y\mapsto\langle y,Y\rangle$$

that allow us to transfer any kind of structure from $X$ to $X\times\{X\}$ and from $Y$ to $Y\times\{Y\}$. All we’ve done, really, is attach a label $X$ to each point of $X$ and a label $Y$ to each point of $Y$, so that even if some $z$ belongs to both $X$ and $Y$, the labelled points $\langle z,X\rangle$ and $\langle z,Y\rangle$ will be distinct. In particular, these maps become homeomorphisms if we take the topology on $X\times\{X\}$ to be

$$\{U\times\{X\}:U\text{ is open in }X\}$$

and similarly for $Y\times\{Y\}$.

Now just define $\sim$ on $X\sqcup Y$ exactly as we did above for the $X\cup Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ are known to be disjoint: for $\langle u,W\rangle,\langle v,Z\rangle\in X\sqcup Y$ (where $u,v\in X\cup Y$ and $W,Z\in\{X,Y\}$), $\langle u,W\rangle\sim\langle v,Z\rangle$ if and only if one of the following is true:

- $\langle u,W\rangle=\langle v,Z\rangle$;
- $u\in A$, $W=X$, $Z=Y$, and $v=f(u)$;
- $v\in A$, $Z=X$, $W=Y$, and $u=f(v)$;
- $u,v\in A$, $W=Z=X$, and $f(u)=f(v)$.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott. Why $X$  and $Y$ are disjoint, so that we don’t have to form $X \bigsqcup Y$??

Comment: @longhoang: Sometimes they are disjoint, and sometimes they are not disjoint. When they are already disjoint, we can use a simpler construction, so I explained that one first. Once it's understood, the general construction that works even when $X$ and $Y$ are not disjoint is easier to understand.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott. I find at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisjointUnion.html, set $X \bigsqcup Y = X\times \{0\} \bigcup  Y\times \{1\},$ so $ X\times \{0\} \bigcup  Y\times \{1\}\neq X\times \{X\} \bigcup Y\times \{Y\}$??  Can you explain for me?

Comment: @longhoang: Both definitions work. All that you really need is two distinct objects $a$ and $b$: then $X\times\{a\}$ is automatically disjoint from $Y\times\{b\}$, just as I explained for the case $a=X$ and $b=Y$. The definition that you were given uses $X$ and $Y$ for $a$ and $b$, because they're handy; the other definition uses $0$ and $1$, which means that the choice of second coordinates doesn't depend on $X$ and $Y$. Both ways do the job.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott. e.g Let $X = \{1, 2\}$ then $X\times \{X\} = \{(1,1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)\}$??

Comment: @longhoang: No. $X\times\{X\}=\{\langle 1,X\rangle,\langle 2,X\rangle\}=\{\langle 1,\{1,2\}\rangle,\langle 2,\{1,2\}\rangle\}$.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott. $\{ \langle 1,\{1,2\}\rangle\} = \{1,\{1,2\}\}$?? or   $\{ \langle 1,\{1,2\}\rangle\} \neq \{1,\{1,2\}\}$??

Comment: @longhoang: No, of course they're not equal. $\{\langle 1,\{1,2\}\rangle\}$ is a set with one element, the ordered pair $\langle 1,\{1,2\}\rangle$, which you would probably write $\{(1,\{1,2\})$; $\{1,\{1,2\}\}$ is a set with two elements, so it clearly cannot be the same set.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott. replace $\langle 1,X\rangle$ by $(1, X) = (1, \{1, 2\})$??

Comment: @longhoang: You can if you wish: they mean exactly the same thing. Both $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $(x,y)$ are standard notations for an ordered pair, and I happen to prefer the first.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott.How to determined topo on $X\bigsqcup Y$ ?? and why this map $X \to X\times \{X\}$  become homeomorphisms if we take the topology on $X \to X\times \{X\}$ to be $\{U\times \{X\}\,\,|\,\,U \mbox{ is open in }  X\}$

Comment: @longhoang: $\{U\times\{X\}:U\text{ is open in }X\}$ is the topology on $X\times\{X\}$; it’s trivial to prove that this makes the map $i_X:X\to X\times\{X\}:x\mapsto\langle x,\{X\}\rangle$ a homeomorphism. Similarly, $\{U\times\{Y\}:U\text{ is open in }Y\}$ is the topology on $Y\times\{Y\}$. The topology on $X\sqcup Y$ is the only one that makes $X\times\{X\}$ and $Y\times\{Y\}$ open subspaces of $X\sqcup Y$ with those same topologies: a subset of $X\sqcup Y$ is open if and only if its intersections with $X\times\{X\}$ and $Y\times\{Y\}$ are both open in those subspaces.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott. How to prove  the map $X\times X \to X$ a continuous??

Comment: @longhoang: Do you mean the map $i_X$? The topology on $X\times\{X\}$ makes it completely trivial that $i_X$ is continuous (and in fact a homeomorphism). Take any open set $U$ in $X\times\{X\}$. If is ***by definition*** of the form $V\times\{X\}$ for some open $V$ in $X$. Now what is $i_X^{-1}[U]$?

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott. No. Let $X$ be a topo space. Prove that the map $X\times X \to X$ a continuous

Comment: @longhoang: *What* map? There are lots of maps from $X\times X$ to $X$. (And what does this have to do with your original question?)

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott. That's my new question is not relevant to the question above. I just want to prove the map $X\times X \to X$ a continuous

Comment: @longhoang: Once again, *what* map from $X\times X$ to $X$? There are lots of them, and unless $X$ has the discrete topology, some are continuous and some are not.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott. Why  if $Y$ is a point, then $X\bigcup\limits_{f} Y  = X\bigsqcup Y/\sim \,\,= X/A$??

Comment: @longhoang: It isn’t actually equal, but it is homeomorphic. If $Y=\{y\}$, the $\sim$-equivalence classes are the sets $\{\langle x,X\rangle\}$ for $x\in X\setminus A$ and $(A\times\{X\})\cup\{\langle y,Y\rangle\}$. The equivalence classes for $X/A$ are the sets $\{x\}$ for $x\in X\setminus A$ and $A$; $\{x\}$ here corresponds to $\{\langle x,X\rangle\}$, and $A$ to $(A\times\{X\})\cup\{\langle y,Y\rangle\}$. The one point of $Y$ doesn’t really do anything: $f$ sends every point of $A$ to $y$, so $\sim$ just lumps all of $A\times\{X\}$ together as a single point, the same way $X/A$ does.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott. I think if $X, Y\neq\emptyset$ then $$ \begin{array}{lll}
X \bigcup\limits_{f}Y&:=& (X\bigsqcup Y)/\sim = (X\times \{X\}\bigcup Y\times \{Y\})/\sim\\
&=& (X\times \{X\}\bigcup Y\times \{Y\})/(A\times \{X\}\bigcup f(A)\times \{Y\}),
\end{array},$$ where $$(u, W)\sim (v, Z) \leftrightarrow \left[\begin{array}{l}
(u, W) =(v, Z),\\
u \in A,\,\,v = f(u),\,\,W = X,\,\,Z = Y,\\
v \in A,\,\,u = f(v),\,\,Z = X,\,\,W = Y,\\
u, v\in A,\,\,W = Z = X,\,\,f(u) = f(v),\\
u, v\in f(A),\,\,W = Z = Y.
\end{array}\right.$$