Equivalence relation of adjunction space
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces and $A \subset X$. Let $f : A \to X$ to be a continuous function. I constructed the adjunction space like here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2032116/1053101

Now just define $\sim$ on $X\sqcup Y$ exactly as we did above for the $X\cup Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ are known to be disjoint: for $\langle u,W\rangle,\langle v,Z\rangle\in X\sqcup Y$ (where $u,v\in X\cup Y$ and $W,Z\in\{X,Y\}$), $\langle u,W\rangle\sim\langle v,Z\rangle$ if and only if one of the following is true:

$\langle u,W\rangle=\langle v,Z\rangle$;
$u\in A$, $W=X$, $Z=Y$, and $v=f(u)$;
$v\in A$, $Z=X$, $W=Y$, and $u=f(v)$;
$u,v\in A$, $W=Z=X$, and $f(u)=f(v)$.


I want to prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. So, suppose that I have $(u, U), (v,V), (w,W)$ with $u,v,w \in X \cup Y$ and $U,V,W \in \{X, Y\}$ such that
$u,v \in A, U = V = X$ and $f(u) = f(v)$ and
$w \in A, W = X, V = Y$ and $f(w) = v$.
So we have $(u,U) \sim (v,V)$ and $(v,V) \sim (w,W)$.
How can I show that $(u,U) \sim (w,W)$?

How is $V$ supposed to be simultaneously $X$ and $Y$…?

It's necessary to be $X \ne Y$ ?

It’s not so much that $X \neq Y$ is necessary, but that when you define $X \sqcup Y$ in the way you wrote down, if $X = Y$ it’s not a disjoint union anymore. Like, $X$ and $Y$ are supposed to be disjoint in $X \sqcup Y$, but with the way you wrote this, $\langle x, X\rangle$ would be simultaneously in the $X$ part of $X \sqcup Y$ and the $Y$ part of $X \sqcup Y$.

The point is, however you define the disjoint union, it must not be the case that $\langle v, V\rangle$ is in both $X$ and $Y$. That fundamentally contradicts with it being a disjoint union.

So this case will be only a contradiction (simply don't work). It will not affect the fact that $\sim$ is equivalence relation. It's true?

I’m not sure what you meant…? In case $X = Y$, you should not have defined $X \sqcup Y$ this way at all, so your question should have been modified to use the correct definition in the first place. In any “correct” definition of the disjoint union, $\sim$ will be an equivalence relation, after being appropriately modified according to the possibly different definition of the disjoint union. As is, if $X = Y$, in your “wrong” definition of the disjoint union, $\sim$ will not be an equivalence relation.

I don't understand what is the correct definition of disjoint union...

Any definition that ensures you have a copy of $X$ and a copy of $Y$ that are disjoint from each other (and, of course, their union is the entire set) works. Disjoint unions are only defined up to bijections, after all.

Your definition only achieves this aim when $X \neq Y$. An easy way to account for the case where $X = Y$ might be, say, $X \sqcup Y = {(x, 0): x \in X} \cup {(y, 1): y \in Y}$. But this is all just notations, really.

Oh. So with this new notation will give $0 = 1$ in that case so it is a contradiction

That’s not how I would phrase it, but sure. It ensures that you can never have $(x, 0) = (y, 1)$, that’s all.

Ok. Thanks! I understand now!
